# Is the main() method of an object deprecated in scala?

Tags: scala

The title about sums it up.  I am inquiring since I use it frequently and a co-worker has stated it were deprecated.  I am looking for evidence one way or the other.

Comment: No, it's not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you believe that the [Dotty](http://dotty.epfl.ch/) is the future of the Scala compilers, then on the contrary it is [the `App` that is partially broken](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped/delayed-init.html).